# Is the Progressive Snapshot worth the money?

Tags: fuel-system

It looks fairly easy to setup and use but can this hurt me? Also, does anyone know how much data they actually store?

EDIT: According to the customer service representative: "Snapshot is a discount only program, so it won’t increase your rate. Depending on your driving habits the discount could reach up to 30%."

This question has been put on hold but as Juann points out you can save $15 a month by refusing this service.

The potential savings of using this are 0-30% of your premium which might be outweighed by the $15 you would save from refusing the service.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it. Rather ask for a discount because you're not taking the device in the first place. The device's cost is worked into your premium. I got a $15 discount on my monthly insurance by refusing the "free" GPS unit they offered.

Aside from that, the real intent of this device is to collect data for when you claim. If they can prove that you went 61 in a 60 zone, they won't pay out.

Comment: So I guess the initial discount of refusing this is $15 a month but the potential savings of using it can be much higher?

Comment: Sure, you can save a lot of money, but they will have MUCH more information on your driving habits, which may be used to deny a payout.